# @Url.Action not working, not showing picture in <img>

Tags: asp.net-mvc, image, url

Ive got this in my EditRound.cshtml

```
<img width="150" height="150" 
            src="@Url.Action("GetImage", "Admin", new {Model.Id})" />
```

And its not showing the picture for some reason.
And my code is

```
public FileContentResult GetImage(int roundId)
    {
        Round round = roundRepository.Rounds.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == roundId);
        if (round != null)
        {
            return File(round.RoundMapImage, round.ImageMimeType);
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

I debugged and everything seems to be okay, but something looks wrong in @Url.Action method. View Page source shows this src="/Admin/GetImage/1  so obviously thats not right, how i can fix this?

Comment: src needs a path to the file, not the actual file..

Comment: How i can fix this, ive tried many things but nothing seems to work

Comment: View Page source shows this src="/Admin/GetImage/1 so obviously thats not right, how i can fix this?

Comment: What do you get when you open `/Admin/GetImage/1` directly in the browser?  Does your action method `GetImage()` gets called?  The comments of @AntP and @bazz are not relevant, @Url.Action returns an URL (as you see with view source) and the browser should call that URL to load the actual image (= call to action method).

Comment: So this is what I get The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'roundId' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.FileContentResult GetImage(Int32)' in 'StadinPeli.WebUI.Controllers.AdminController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
Parameter name: parameters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `/Admin/GetImage/1` is incorrect then you could try using:

```
<img width="150" height="150" 
        src="@Url.Action("GetImage", "Admin", new { roundId = Model.Id})" />
```

That should give you a path in the form `/Admin/GetImage?roundId=1`

Comment: @pkunal7 I'm trying the exactly same example. And on my html i can see that it is passing it the wright way <img width="250" height="250"
                scr= "/Sells/GetImage?oscar=4" /> and on the parameter on the controller instead of (int roundId )i have(int oscar) But when i put a breakpint on the Getimage method it doesnot hits it. any ideas why ? Any help would be great  thanks

Comment: @omachu23 That's interesting. What is the error you get? If you put the URL to the GetImage method in the browser, does it ever get anything back (even an HTTP error code) or does it time out?

Comment: @pkunal7 I found the mistake i misspell src and that was it. I know very dumb problem! Thanks for taking the time to answer my question !

Comment: @omachu23 not to worry, i should have spotted that too!

Answer (score -1):

Please replace new {Model.Id} to new { ID = item.ID }